# How do I 'build' my web app for deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, web-applications, aws-amplify

I've created a basic web app using Node.js, Express, Mustache and MongoDB. It's *really* basic, all it does is use routes and controllers to display mustache files (I've included a screenshot of my project's directory structure for some context). I'd now like to deploy it on AWS Amplify. In order to do that, I need to provide Amplify with a 'build' command. Normally, to run my app locally, I'd just use the command 'node index.js'. index.js contains this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require('./routes/routes')
const mustache = require('mustache-express');
require('dotenv').config()
const path = require('path');
const public = path.join(__dirname, 'public');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

app.use(express.static(public));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser())
app.engine('mustache', mustache());
app.set('view engine', 'mustache');
app.use('/', router);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

When I set the build command as 'npm install', Amplify can successfully build and deploy the app. However, when I visit the URL Amplify provides, it shows a 404 error, and the browser console looks like it's searching for a file called 'index.html'... I'd really like for it to just start the app like I do when I use the command 'node index.js'. Can anyone help? If I can provide more context, just let me know.

[image: project dir structure]